# How don't insert duplicate objects in db4o

Tags: java

I'm trying to add one one objetct with the same dni, but i always have an excepcion (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at GestionPersistencia.insertarVehiculo(GestionPersistencia.java:65)
        at Principal.main(Principal.java:22)
    [db4o 8.0.249.16098   2014-12-30 01:31:27] )

```
My Main class..

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p = new Person("Jesus", 25, "50667847L");
        Persistence g = new Persistence();

        g.insertPerson(p);


My Class Persistence....

    public void insertarPersona(Person p){
     EmbeddedConfiguration CONFIGURATION = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();  
      CONFIGURATION.common().objectClass(Vehiculo.class).objectField("matricula").indexed(true);  
      CONFIGURATION.common().add(new UniqueFieldValueConstraint(Vehiculo.class, "matricula")); 
       bbd = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(CONFIGURATION,"fgd.db4o");
            try {  
                bbdd.store(p);
                bbdd.commit();
                  } catch (UniqueFieldValueConstraintViolationException e) {  
                   bbdd.rollback();  
                  } 
                bbdd.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell from the piece of Code you provided if there is any different problem, but you seem to have a typo in this line:

```
bbd = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(CONFIGURATION,"fgd.db4o");
```

I guess `bdd` should be `bbdd` as you are using it here:

```
bbdd.store(p);
```

By the way, the exception you provided is refering to a method `GestionPersistencia.insertarVehiculo`, you should post this method instead of `insertarPersona` and provide line numbers so we can tell which statement causes the crash.